# different screen.colorDepth value for firefox and opera/chrome

Tags: javascript

I m testing a javascript in which i wrote this

```
document.write("\n\n\n\n"+screen.colorDepth);
switch(screen.colorDepth)
{
case 24: document.bgColor = "skyblue" ;
         break;
case 32: document.bgColor = "yellow";
        break;
default: document.bgColor = "white";
        break;
}
```

but unfortunately Firefox 21.0 and IE9 is showing value 24 and thus background color is going skyblue
and opera( v12.01 Build 1532) and chrome(Version 27.0.1453.94 m) is showing 32 and thus the background is going yellow . I m using win 7 ultimate 32bit and my original color depth of screen is 32 bit. Can anyone plz explain why this is happening ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess they are using different approaches interpreting the color precision. A 32-bit screen is in fact only 24-bit color (the [8 last bits is not part of the color space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth#Direct_color)).

[Mozilla defines](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.screen.colorDepth) it as:

> Returns the color depth of the screen.

Chrome seem to read it directly from the system as-is, while FF and IE9 seem to correctly (based on that definition) identify the color precision (color depth) of the screen.

Please note that `screen.colorDepth` is not part of any standard and it's up to the implementers how it actually works.

The more correct way of checking color-precision in regards to color depth would therefor be:

```
case 16: document.bgColor = "..." ;
         break;
case 24:
case 32: document.bgColor = "..."; //32 = 24 bit color depth + 8 bits alpha
         break;
```