# screen.colorDepth always returns 24

Tags: javascript

I'm just wondering if there are ways to detect OS color depth. For me it always returns 24 no matter if i have 32bit or 16bits screen. Tested on chrome and ff.

OS: Windows 7

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/tests/screenview.html#color

Comment: Is that an answer you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930540/different-screen-colordepth-value-for-firefox-and-opera-chrome ?

Comment: No, Both FF 35/36, Chrome 41 always returns 24 even if i'm on 16 bit windows.

Comment: I need to find if user is on High color or True Color. High color is not even 24 bit's long

Comment: It looks like you should try doing it in CSS instead: `@media all and (max-color: 7) {
 body {background: #CCC; color: #333;}
}` The reason why is: [Internet Explorer 9 always returns a value of 32.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531087(v=vs.85).aspx) and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=424386. Also [Right now Firefox 3.6 returns 24 when you query colorDepth/pixelDepth](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/06/more_ie9_goodne.html). Read more about [media queries here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).